# How can I calculate the normal distribution numerically using the Gaussian function?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have the following: $$P(S(t) < 0) = N\Big(-\frac{S_0e^{\mu t}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}(e^{2\mu t} -1)}}\Big).$$

(Or something along those lines.) Some of you may recognise this as the probability of a stock price being less than zero.

I want to now calculate this probability numerically, with the values $\mu=0.1$, $\sigma=0.3$, $S_0=25$, and $t=1$. (My calculator is not an updated version that does normal distribution probabilities.

I know that a Gaussian is given by $$N(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$ I have also seen $$N(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$ Which would I use in this case? There are a number of ways I have considered doing this:

1. Compute the numerical value of the argument of N(),such that I end up with N(x). Then use the second Gaussian equation to find N(x).
2. Compute the numerical value of the argument of N(), such that I end up with N(x). Then use the first Gaussian to find N(x), repeating my use of $\sigma$ and $\mu.$

Option 1 seems most likely. Could someone please clarify the correct way to do this.

Comment: Well you can transform any Gaussian distribution from that of mean 0 and standard deviation 1 to that of $\mu, \sigma $ by $N (\mu,\sigma)=N (0,1).\sigma +\mu $

Comment: @Malcolm I don't see how this is used. What Do I use as N(0, 1) numerically in a calculator?